# Hibernate One-to-One generates Delete on creation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm facing a strange problem when creating hibernate object with One-to-One cascade. 
A Delete statement is generated, when no delete is needed.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role extends Translatable {
    //business fields
}
```

Role can be translated and extends:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Translatable{

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSLATION_ID", updatable = false)
    @Getter @Setter
    private TranslationPack translationPack;
}
```

Package consists of a set of different translations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSLATION_PACK")
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class TranslationPack{
    //id declaration skipped

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "translationPack", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Getter @Setter
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Translation> translations;
}
```

UPD:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSLATION")
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Translation implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    @Getter @Setter
    private TranslationId translationId;

    @Column(name = "TRANSLATION", length = 255)
    @Getter  @Setter
    private String translation;

    @MapsId("languageCode")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(updatable = false, name = "LANGUAGE_CODE")
    @Getter  @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    private LanguagePack languagePack;

    @MapsId("translationPackId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(updatable = false, name = "TRANSLATION_PACK_ID")
    @Getter  @Setter
    private TranslationPack translationPack;

    @Embeddable
    @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class TranslationId implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_CODE")
        @Getter @Setter
        String languageCode;

        @Column(name = "TRANSLATION_PACK_ID")
        @Getter  @Setter
        Long translationPackId;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() ; //skipping

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object); //skipping
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() ; //skipping

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object object); //skipping
}
```

When a save a role with one translation a get the following:

```
Hibernate: select ROLE_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select TRANSLATION_PACK_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into TRANSLATION_PACK (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into ROLE (TRANSLATION_ID, CODE, NAME, ROLE_TYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TRANSLATION_PACK (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into TRANSLATION (TRANSLATION, LANGUAGE_CODE, TRANSLATION_PACK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update ROLE set CODE=?, NAME=?, ROLE_TYPE=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from TRANSLATION_PACK where id=?
```

> Oracle constraints fail, on Foreign Key for TRANSLATION_ID validation
>   (o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-02292).

What is the problem with my mapping? Or is hibernate using some temporary id?
***(My hibernate version is 4.2.7 and cannot be upgraded unfortunately)***

UPDATE:
Changing to

```
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSLATION_ID", updatable = true)
    @Getter @Setter
    private TranslationPack translationPack;
```

(updatable **true**)

Started generated normal scripts:

```
 Hibernate: select ROLE_SEQ.nextval from dual
 Hibernate: select TRANSLATION_PACK_SEQ.nextval from dual
 Hibernate: insert into TRANSLATION_PACK (id) values (?)
 Hibernate: insert into ROLE (TRANSLATION_ID, CODE, NAME, ROLE_TYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I don't think it's a suitable solution, since I wanted to control that id is never changed.

Comment: Can you share the Translation class?

Comment: @Amer Qarabsa , sure, but i don't think it's a child entity fault

Comment: Can you show the code where you create and save the Role entity? Also, could you please elaborate on what you mean with "I want to control that id is never changed"?

Comment: @Kirinya, I want the translation_id to be prevented from update, insert allowed only. (updatable = false was supposed to achieve this)

Comment: @Kirinya, save is simple: myrepositoty.save(role); The entity is ok, collections are created, dual-binding for child entities done.

Comment: I see two different options for "keeping ID": a) Make sure that IDs in TranslationPack are never changed, i.e. TranslationPack "english-1" keeps ID 1 whatever happens OR b) Make sure that your role, once created, can never change its TranslationPack - which one applies in your case?

Comment: @Kirinya  Make sure that your role, once created, can never change its TranslationPack - this one

Comment: I think that in this case I would use cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST in the role entity, and make sure the role entity has no setter for TranslationPack, but only the parameter in the constructor.

Comment: @Kirinya, I'm not sure it's a solution, since it means, that deleting Role will not delete it's translations and they should be deleted manually.